# What is the fee for opening the door in The Last Car?

Tags: plot-explanation, tales-from-the-darkside

In the episode "[The Last Car](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716990/)" from the *[Tales from the Darkside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside)*, what is the fee for opening the door? When the woman tries to open the door she is warned about a fee but the amount is never revealed.

Comment: Probably her soul?

Comment: @DustinDavis: It may be possible, but it looks like it is a monetary sum, the mystery is why the woman does not finish the sentence.